# Iframe full screen not working in Chrome?

Tags: html, iframe

I am integrating Slideshare in my website. Slide presentation is coming fine in small window. But the problem is slide presentation in full screen is not coming in Chrome(website slider itself displaying in full screen). In Mozilla its working fine. Only issue with Chrome. 
Website link: http://test.kiadb.in/

place used the iframe is next to invest Karnataka image refer image [image]

---

```
This code I have used for Iframe <iframe src="http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/56692337" frameborder="2" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 16):

try this way

```
<iframe src="http://yourpage.com" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/56692337" frameborder="2" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Iframe is not inserted in another iframe embed code. If that is the case, the parent iFrame must have the allowfullscreen="true" parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got a error in console
just try to solve that

[Error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuKYP.png)

and try this iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/56692337" frameborder="2" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" frameborder="0"
```