# slideshare Iframe fullscreen not working on chrome

Tags: wordpress, html, iframe

On my wordpress website I have integrated slideshare on a page. The problem is that the full screen in not working in google chrome(in firefox it works).
Here is my code :

```
<iframe style="border: 1px solid #CCC; border-width: 1px; margin-bottom: 5px; max-width: 100%;" src="mylink_here" width="595" height="485" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" oallowfullscreen="true" msallowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>
```

I have tried this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627460/iframe-full-screen-not-working-in-chrome)
but no results

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, well when I commented the line below, fullscreen work perfectly :

```
<link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I don't know how does animate.css affect slideshare on fullscreen but this solution works for me :)